# Get one or more column values as a list from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

For the given `dataframe`

```
  Bin1  Bin2  Bin3
0    A     1     7
1    B     2     8
2    C     3     9
```

I want a list of values from `Bin1` and `Bin3` columns

I tried,

```
df[["Bin1","Bin3"]].values.tolist()
```

But it is not giving the expected list.

My desired output is,

```
output_df = ["A","B","C",7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of lists and then [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
l = df[["Bin1","Bin3"]].values.T.tolist()

flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
print (flat_list)
['A', 'B', 'C', 7, 8, 9]
```

Similar, thanks  [Bharath shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585640/how-to-get-one-or-more-datacolumn-values-as-a-list-in-python/46585713#comment80124287_46585713):

```
flat_list = df[["Bin1","Bin2"]].values.T.flatten().tolist()
```

Comment: `df[["Bin1","Bin2"]].values.flatten().tolist()`?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
df['Bin1'].tolist() + df['Bin3'].tolist()

['A', 'B', 'C', 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Few other ways

**Option 1** `unstack`

```
In [1413]: df[['Bin1', 'Bin3']].unstack().values.tolist()
Out[1413]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 7L, 8L, 9L]
```

**Option 2** `ravel`

```
In [1426]: df[['Bin1', 'Bin3']].values.ravel(order='A')
Out[1426]: array(['A', 'B', 'C', 7L, 8L, 9L], dtype=object)
```

---

<sub>Timings</sub>

```
In [1446]: df.shape
Out[1446]: (60000, 3)

In [1447]: %timeit df['Bin1'].values.tolist() + df['Bin3'].values.tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop

In [1440]: %timeit df['Bin1'].tolist() + df['Bin3'].tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.87 ms per loop

In [1442]: %timeit df[['Bin1', 'Bin3']].values.ravel(order='A').tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.86 ms per loop

In [1443]: %timeit df[['Bin1', 'Bin3']].unstack().values.tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 9.32 ms per loop

In [1444]: %timeit df[["Bin1","Bin2"]].values.T.flatten().tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.91 ms per loop

In [1445]: %timeit [it for subl in df[["Bin1","Bin3"]].values.T.tolist() for it in subl]
10 loops, best of 3: 20.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `melt`

```
df[['Bin1','Bin3']].melt().value.tolist()
Out[382]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as: `list(df[["Bin1","Bin2"]].as_matrix().flatten())`